# jquery ajax not doing login on form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I have a login page. Where user puts his email,password and when clicks on login then he makes login.
Now I have taken those input fields in a form and made a jquery ajax to login to the same form. But it is not doing login. I have tried the console tab for error debug, it shows me status 200 but nothing happens.
 The reference login where user makes login is [here](http://sfcmp.com/secure/login)
 and my markup code for login is like this

```
 <form action="#" class="form-horizontal" id="loginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <label for="email">
          <span class="text">Email</span>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="span3" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your email address">
        </label>
        <label for="password">
          <span class="text">Password</span>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" class="span3" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter the password">
         </label>
            <input name="remember" id="remember" value="true" type="hidden">
         <input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
```

and my ajax code goes like this

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#loginForm').submit(function(event) {
    var url = "http://sfcmp.com/secure/login";
  var data = {
    Email: jQuery('div.modal-body form.form-horizontal input#email').val(),
    Password:  jQuery('div.modal-body form.form-horizontal input#password').val(),
    LoggedIn: jQuery('div.modal-body form.form-horizontal input#remember').val()
  }
  console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        console.log(err.Message);
      }

    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

So can someone kindly tell me whats the error here and how can I login the form using ajax?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"?  What's *supposed* to happen?  All you do on a success condition is log the status.

Comment: We're probably going to need to see the contents of `http://sfcmp.com/secure/login` to be of use.

Comment: nothing happens means in console tab it is showing status 200 but when I am going to login page it is showing not logged in...

Comment: write something in success function like location.href="path to new page". Then only it will work

Comment: `"when I am going to login page it is showing not logged in"` - That's not really something we can help diagnose since you haven't provided any information about that page or how you track your logged-in users.

Answer (score 0):

i didnt find any problem here .
The ajax page calls perfectly

```
http://sfcmp.com/secure/login?email=test%40mail.com&password=password&submit=Login&redirect=&submitted=submitted
```

do check your authentication php code at http://sfcmp.com/secure/login

Answer (score 0):

I take it from the fact that you are using an absolute path that this script isnt running on the same server as `sfcmp.com`. If this is the case you are having an issue with cross origin policy. However I tested your script and the network call triggers, but hit a cross origin error.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Hope this helps. Let me know if you are running it from the same server.

Comment: It is in the same server

Answer (score 0):

If your controler method expect post data, you should use [jQuery.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)  to serialize your form, and post it via ajax.Do not post json. Hope this help.